# elasticbeanstalk deployment failing with Error response from daemon:

Tags: docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

AWS Elastic Beanstalk failing with error response from daemon:

You cannot remove a running container c911e29b2ce2283bae300645bf2f034f7bf51c07b7ec72c6ebfa133d531a6129.

Stop the container before attempting removal or force remove

Error log bellow:

```
2020/04/26 07:15:31.279931 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c docker rmi `docker images -aq`
2020/04/26 07:15:31.369738 [ERROR] Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete 274bac0a2621 (cannot be forced) - image has dependent child images
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete 6040329cd021 (cannot be forced) - image has dependent child images
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete 1020a81a3f38 (cannot be forced) - image is being used by running container c911e29b2ce2
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete 68e7be49c28c (cannot be forced) - image has dependent child images

2020/04/26 07:15:31.369787 [INFO] restore docker image name with command: docker tag 1020a81a3f38 aws_beanstalk/current-app:latest
2020/04/26 07:15:31.369804 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c docker tag 1020a81a3f38 aws_beanstalk/current-app:latest
2020/04/26 07:15:31.414707 [INFO] restore docker image name with command: docker tag 68e7be49c28c python:2.7
2020/04/26 07:15:31.414786 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c docker tag 68e7be49c28c python:2.7
2020/04/26 07:15:31.462282 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /bin/file -m /opt/elasticbeanstalk/config/private/beanstalk-magic -b --mime-type /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/app_source_bundle
2020/04/26 07:15:31.464666 [INFO] application/zip

2020/04/26 07:15:31.464679 [INFO] app source bundle is zip file ...
2020/04/26 07:15:31.464689 [INFO] extracting /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/app_source_bundle to /var/app/current/
2020/04/26 07:15:31.464703 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /usr/bin/unzip -q -o /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/app_source_bundle -d /var/app/current/
2020/04/26 07:15:31.475355 [INFO] finished extracting /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/app_source_bundle to /var/app/current/ successfully
2020/04/26 07:15:31.475367 [INFO] Executing instruction: RunPreBuildHooks
2020/04/26 07:15:31.475381 [INFO] The dir .platform/hooks/prebuild/ does not exist in the application. Skipping this step...
2020/04/26 07:15:31.475385 [INFO] Executing instruction: Docker Specific Build Application
2020/04/26 07:15:31.475404 [INFO] start build docker app
2020/04/26 07:15:31.475414 [INFO] fetch image name
2020/04/26 07:15:31.475437 [INFO] authenticate with ECR if the image is in an ECR repo
2020/04/26 07:15:31.475442 [INFO] pull docker image if update is not false in dockerrun.aws.json
2020/04/26 07:15:31.475455 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c docker pull node:alpine as builder
2020/04/26 07:15:31.516536 [ERROR] "docker pull" requires exactly 1 argument.
See 'docker pull --help'.

Usage:  docker pull [OPTIONS] NAME[:TAG|@DIGEST]

Pull an image or a repository from a registry

2020/04/26 07:15:31.516557 [WARN] failed to execute command: docker pull node:alpine as builder, retrying...
2020/04/26 07:15:31.516577 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c docker pull node:alpine as builder
2020/04/26 07:15:31.557381 [ERROR] "docker pull" requires exactly 1 argument.
See 'docker pull --help'.

Usage:  docker pull [OPTIONS] NAME[:TAG|@DIGEST]

Pull an image or a repository from a registry

2020/04/26 07:15:31.557405 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [Docker Specific Build Application]. Stop running the command. Error: failed to pull docker image: Command /bin/sh -c docker pull node:alpine as builder failed with error exit status 1. Stderr:"docker pull" requires exactly 1 argument.
See 'docker pull --help'.
```

Comment: This is working fine in travis and local, But docker is failing in elasticbeanstalk

Answer (score 8):

We had a problem like this on the following Platform: `Docker running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.0.0`
Switching to `Docker running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.14.3` solved the problem - Docker image builds as expected.

Comment: I would give you a thousand upvotes! You saved me hours of debugging probably!

Comment: Faced this problem with 3.4.19, switching to 3.4.5 fixed it for me.

Comment: How do you go about changing the linux version? when initializing through the CL it only gives two options, which are listed as:   



1) Docker running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2
2) ECS running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2
(default is 1):